# Multiple FileSystemWatchers to monitor same folder

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I have an existing windows service that uses FileSystemWatcher object to monitor one folder. Now, I would like to create another windows service that uses the FileSystemWatcher object to monitor the same folder. So, can someone please clarify me on below questions ?

1. Is there a restriction on number of FileSystemWatchers monitoring the same folder ?
2. how do we handle the file lock or access issues such as when one FileSystemWatcher is being written to the directory and the other is trying to read the same file ?
3. Any other implications on this set-up?

Regards,
Ram

Comment: Could someone please reply to my question ? Its bit urgent.

Comment: Anyone can please help answer my questions ?

Comment: Could someone please reply to my questions ?

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with a similar situation. I have the same service installed and running on 2 machines. Each is monitoring the same collection of folders on a network.

In my experience:

1. Having 2 services each monitoring the same network share location(s) is not a problem - both will react.
2. My FSW triggers a file-copy from the monitored location to another network location. Since both instances of the service react, both will attempt the copy. One of my services throws an error (which I try..catch) the other does the work. This is a satisfactory solution for me although I appreciate it's not very "tidy".
3. The FSW is remarkably unreliable. I'm currently dealing with a situation where the network connection fails and I'm having to restart my filewatchers. there are plenty of examples of ways to restart a FSW on SO... Personally, I'm setting off a timer in the onError event and recreating my FSW(s) after 30 seconds. Yes, I'm recreating it - i read advice that a simple ".EnableRaisingEvents=true;" would not work well enough.

HTH